# Hilbert space linear operator question

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the vector space of all complex-valued, absolutely continuous functions on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f^{'}\in L^2[0,1]$.  Define an inner product on $\mathcal{H}$ by 
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1f^{'}(x)\overline{g^{'}(x)}dx
$$ for $f,g\in\mathcal{H}$.

If $0<x\leq 1$, define $L:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $L(f)=f(x)$.  Show $L$ is a bounded linear functional and find $\|L\|$.

I was able to show $L$ is linear.  That was easy.  I am having trouble showing it is bounded and I cannot determine what $\|L\|$ is.

Comment: There is a very similar exercise on Eidelman-Milman-Tsolomitis's book [(click)](http://books.google.it/books?id=bzUgKyoaQocC&lpg=PP1&hl=it&pg=PA44#v=onepage&q&f=false)(with solution). A nice remark: This functional $L$ is exactly a Dirac's delta concentrated at $x$.

Comment: I cannot find the solution.

Comment: You're right, Google preview trimmed it. You need pages 246-247.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
|L(f)|=
\left|\int\limits_{0}^xf'(t)dt+f(0)\right|=
\left|\int\limits_{0}^xf'(t)dt\right|\leq
\left(\int\limits_{0}^x|f'(t)|^2dt\right)^{1/2}
\left(\int\limits_{0}^x|1|^2dt\right)^{1/2}=
$$
$$
\sqrt{x}\left(\int\limits_{0}^x|f'(t)|^2dt\right)^{1/2}\leq
\sqrt{x}\left(\int\limits_{0}^1|f'(t)|^2dt\right)^{1/2}
=\sqrt{x}\Vert f \Vert
$$

Answer (score 0):

The operator $L_x$ evaluates the function at the point $x$, 
that is, $L_x(f)=f(x)$.
As Norbert shows, the norm of this operator is less than or equal to $\sqrt{x}$.

For the piecewise linear function
$f(y)={y\over \sqrt{x}}\wedge \sqrt{x}$, we see that 
this upper bound is achieved, and so deduce that  $\|L_x\|=\sqrt{x}$.